# Yarn "command not found" when switching node with nvm from 18 to 14

Tags: yarnpkg, nvm

I am running node 18 (installed with nvm) and everything is fine. `Yarn` works fine.
However when I switch to node 14 `nvm use 14` then yarn cannot be found `zsh: command not found: yarn`.

If I run `nvm use 18` then `yarn` once again works fine.

How can I make yarn work on node 14 and 18? I am using yarn version `1.22.19`

Answer (score 1):

When you install a new node version using nvm and then used npm to install yarn, you need to reinstall the yarn for the new node version.

Try:

`nvm install 8.11.3 nvm use 8.11.3 npm install -g yarn`

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174381/yarn-not-installing-in-nvm-version-node-version)

Answer (score 1):

**The Solution:**

Before installing the new version you need to add a flag to your command. for more information check the `nvm` documentation in [Migrating Global Packages While Installing](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#migrating-global-packages-while-installing)

```bash
$ nvm install 18 --reinstall-packages-from=14
```

You have two options:

1. Uninstall your `node v18` and reinstall it

```bash
$ nvm use 14
$ nvm uninstall 18
$ nvm install 18 --reinstall-packages-from=14
```

2. Get the list of installed packages and install them again

**The Explanation:**

By using `nvm` each version of `node` and its related `npm` will be installed in a different directory.
You can check the directory with the command `which`:

```bash
$ which node
/Users/ali/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node

$ which npm
/Users/ali/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/npm

$ nvm use v20
Now using node v20.9.0 (npm v10.1.0)

$ which node
/Users/ali/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin/node

$ which npm
/Users/ali/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/bin/npm
```

So it looks like a clear installation without any predefined packages.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other options work, you can reinstall Yarn on the affected Node version. I encountered the same issue with switching over Node versions, caused by a local cache issue in ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v18.17.1-linux-x64/node-v18.17.1-linux-x64.tar.xz4.

The issue was resolved by reinstalling yarn globally.

```
npm install --global yarn
```